# Different dependencies for different environments with dep

Tags: go, build, dependencies, dependency-management, dep

How can I ensure that I use different dependencies depending on the environment/build? For example, I do not want to include some dependencies required for the testing environment in my production build?

Comment: Are you importing those testing dependencies only in your *_test.go files? If so, those files aren't included in go-build's output, neither are the deps imported in those files.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for your answer. could you please show some source for this info?

Comment: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies *" When compiling packages, build ignores files that end in '_test.go'. "*

Comment: @mkopriva thanks a lot for the info. If I am importing the dependency A in _test.go file, and the dependency B is imported only in A, would B included in go-build or not? Technically, B is not imported only in _test.go file. 
How can I even verify this myself?